# C+11-Like Type Decay in Rust

Tags: c++11, macros, rust

In C++11, you can decay a generic type to a value type, removing reference/rvalue semantics and cv-qualifiers, e.g.

```
decay<int>::type // type is `int`
decay<const int&>::type // type is `int`
decay<int&&>::type // type is `int`
```

Is there a known mechanism to achieve the same in Rust, that strips reference modifiers, lifetimes and the `mut` qualifier? e.g.:

```
decay<u32>::type <--- type is `u32`
decay<&u32>::type <--- type is `u32`
decay<&mut u32>::type <--- type is `u32`
decay<&static u32>::type <--- type is `u32`
```

For background, I'm trying to write a macro that generates a `struct` that stores the values of a bunch of function arguments matched by the macro. e.g., the macro might contain the args `foo: i32, bar: &Vec<String>`, and the resultant struct should be:

```
struct GeneratedStruct {
    foo: i32,
    bar: Vec<String>,
}
```

Comment: I think in Rust this would be handled directly by the macro, rather than using traits (though you could create the trait yourself). Remember than Rust macros operate on the Abstract Syntax Tree, not text, so you can actually *parse* your arguments in the macro.

Comment: Deref can turn &T into T, but if I'm not mistaken there's no way to know that T isn't itself some &.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I don't think macro can help, e.g. `type I32Ref = &'static i32; ...; decay!(I32Ref)` should produce `i32`, but there is no way this is known in the lexical level.

Comment: @kennytm: Ah, indeed in the presence of aliases...

Comment: @kennytm: I had an idea of creating a `trait Decay { type Type; }` however... while it can be implemented for both `&'a T` and `&'a mut T`, I cannot also implement it for just `T` as that conflicts.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You could use specialization to resolve the conflict, but [then `<T as Decay>::Type` would never be resolved](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md#the-default-keyword).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by [Matthieu M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147192/matthieu-m) and [kennytm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224671/kennytm) in comments, you can define a trait and use specialization (an unstable feature as of Rust 1.15.0) to achieve this.

```rust
#![feature(specialization)]

use std::any::TypeId;

trait Decay {
    type Type;
}

impl<T> Decay for T {
    default type Type = T;
}

impl<'a, T> Decay for &'a T {
    type Type = <T as Decay>::Type;
}

impl<'a, T> Decay for &'a mut T {
    type Type = <T as Decay>::Type;
}

fn foo<T: 'static>() {
    println!("{:?}", TypeId::of::<T>());
}

fn bar<T>() where <T as Decay>::Type: 'static {
    println!("{:?}", TypeId::of::<<T as Decay>::Type>());
}

fn main() {
    foo::<<i32 as Decay>::Type>();
    foo::<<&i32 as Decay>::Type>();
    foo::<<&mut i32 as Decay>::Type>();
    foo::<<&&i32 as Decay>::Type>();

    bar::<i32>();
    bar::<&i32>();
    bar::<&mut i32>();
    bar::<&&i32>();
}
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know specialization could apply to associated types (never thought about it, really).

Comment: Nice! This does the job. I'd rather not make my library unstable-only though. I'm going to continue looking into this and see if I can come up with a way to do this using stable-only features.